# How do I specify "close existing connections" in sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing active development on my schema in SQL Server 2008 and frequently want to rerun my drop/create database script. When I run

```
USE [master]
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'MyDatabase')
DROP DATABASE [MyDatabase]
GO
```

I often get this error

```
Msg 3702, Level 16, State 4, Line 3
Cannot drop database "MyDatabase" because it is currently in use.
```

If you right click on the database in the object explorer pane and select the Delete task from the context menu, there is a checkbox which to "close existing connections"

Is there a way to specify this option in my script?

Answer (score 294, accepted):

You can disconnect everyone and roll back their transactions with:

```
alter database [MyDatbase] set single_user with rollback immediate
```

After that, you can safely drop the database :)

Comment: I've used this but often wondered if there was a window of opportunity for another user to get in as the "single user" - is that possible?  Possible alternative is ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabaseName] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

Comment: The user in single_user is you; unless you disconnect after setting single user mode.  Then one (1) other user can log on.

Comment: Once you've dropped the database, if you create a new one with the same name I presume it will be in multi_user mode? So you don't have to run: alter database [MyDatbase] set multi_user

Comment: @AndyM: Yeah, multi_user is probably the default

Comment: @Kristen Using your approach I found the sql server doesn't remove the mdf and ldf files. Set single_user works fine to me (I need to constantly recreate the db).

Comment: @2xMax: Setting database to OFFLINE isn't intended to remove the files as you could subsequently set it to ONLINE to reinstate the database.  OFFLINE allows you to, for example, make a physical file copy. DROP the database if you don't want it anymore, or just RESTORE with same filenames as the original when you are having to "recreate the db" (which will be faster on the restore, especially for large files, as the existing files will be re-used without having to pre-create a new file

Comment: @AndyM: database, after restore, will be in the same state as the database that the backup was made from; e.g. backup a database which is in Single User mode: that's what the restored database will be too. The state of the database being restored over has no effect. (Old comment I know, just wanted to clarify for others who may read this in the future)

Comment: Using this example, I couldn't get in the database myself anymore. I fixed that by setting it back to MULTI_USER in the end of my script.

Comment: Doesn't work -- says there are still connections to the database, had to go with @Kristen's approach.

Answer (score 44):

Go to management studio and do everything you describe, only instead of clicking OK, click on Script. It will show the code it will run which you can then incorporate in your scripts.

In this case, you want:

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

Comment: I was going to try to answer this question by doing exactly what you describe (scripting the "delete database" dialog) but it **doesn't** add the ALTER DATABASE line to the script if you check the "close existing connections" checkbox.

Comment: The script generating from the wizard included the 'alter database' line for me.

Comment: Weird. Which Management Studio version? I'm on 2008 x64.

Comment: Me too:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.0.1600.22 
Operating System 6.0.6001

Comment: Had the same problem with ALTER DATABASE not being added to the script. In order for me to get it added to the script I had to make sure I had a process running (active connection) against that database when the script was generated.

Answer (score 18):

According to the [ALTER DATABASE SET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) documentation, there is still a possibility that after setting a database to SINGLE_USER mode you won't be able to access that database:

> Before you set the database to SINGLE_USER, verify the AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC option is set to OFF. When set to ON, the background thread used to update statistics takes a connection against the database, and you will be unable to access the database in single-user mode.

So, a complete script to drop the database with existing connections may look like this:

```
DECLARE @dbId int
DECLARE @isStatAsyncOn bit
DECLARE @jobId int
DECLARE @sqlString nvarchar(500)

SELECT @dbId = database_id,
       @isStatAsyncOn = is_auto_update_stats_async_on
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'db_name'

IF @isStatAsyncOn = 1
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [db_name] SET  AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF

    -- kill running jobs
    DECLARE jobsCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT job_id
    FROM sys.dm_exec_background_job_queue
    WHERE database_id = @dbId

    OPEN jobsCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM jobsCursor INTO @jobId
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        set @sqlString = 'KILL STATS JOB ' + STR(@jobId)
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlString
        FETCH NEXT FROM jobsCursor INTO @jobId
    END

    CLOSE jobsCursor
    DEALLOCATE jobsCursor
END

ALTER DATABASE [db_name] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

DROP DATABASE [db_name]
```

Answer (score 11):

I know it's too late but may be its helps some one. on using this take your database offline

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET OFFLINE
```

Comment: remark: after "drop offline database", file Mdf not dropped!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154141/drop-db-but-dont-delete-mdf-ldf

Comment: Run `ALTER DATABASE dbname SET ONLINE` just after running the OFFLINE command of this answer. SQL server will only delete the associated files (mdf, ldf) for online databases. By running the offline and online statement consecutively, all existing connections will be dropped, and SQL will delete all db files correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I tryed what hgmnz saids on SQL Server 2012.

Management created to me:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'MyDataBase'
GO
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [MyDataBase]    Script Date: 09/09/2014 15:58:46 ******/
DROP DATABASE [MyDataBase]
GO
```

Comment: This will not close the active connections.

Comment: Make sure you checked "Close existing connections"; If you don the `ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` statement will be included. The `sp_delete_database_backuphistory` comes from checking the "Delete backup and restore history information for databases".

Comment: Checking "Close existing connections" doesn't generate the `ALTER DATABASE SET SINGLE_USER ...` if there are no current connections to close.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to drop it from you application, your connection string's initial catalog must be "master"

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

See below. Do not click OK, but Ctrl + Shift + N, and a new window with the script will be ready for you.

[image: Drop Database Dialog for script generation]

Answer (score -2):

try this C# code to drop your database

public static void DropDatabases(string dataBase)
        {

```
        string sql =  "ALTER DATABASE "  + dataBase + "SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE" ;

        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBRestore"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandTimeout = 7200;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            sql = "DROP DATABASE " + dataBase;
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandTimeout = 7200;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```