# Why is Sql Server database busy?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to create a database, run some tests on it, then drop the database:

```
namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string testConnectionString = @"Server=localhost\SQL2014EXPRESS64; Database=RepoTest; Trusted_Connection=True;";
            const string masterConnectionString = @"Server=localhost\SQL2014EXPRESS64; Database=master; Trusted_Connection=True;";

            // connect to master and create RepoTest db
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(masterConnectionString))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE RepoTest", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            // connect to RepoTest and create some new tables
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(testConnectionString))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE Test(ID INT NOT NULL)", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            // connect to master and delete RepoTest db
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(masterConnectionString))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("DROP DATABASE RepoTest", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this Exception when trying to drop the test database:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Cannot drop database "RepoTest" because it is currently in use.

But I expected it to no longer be in use as the part that was using that database was in a using block so I expected the connection to be closed and the operation to be complete, if this isn't the case is there a command I can use to drop the database when its finished its current process?

Comment: Just for kicks and giggles, put a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` just before the third section.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469130/cannot-drop-database-because-it-is-currently-in-use) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069661/dropping-sql-server-database-through-c-sharp) for some ideas.

Comment: Try adding `pooling=false` to your connection strings to disable connection pooling.

Comment: Have you considered creating tables and other objects in `tempdb` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection object using the testConnectionString will use pooling.
Disable pooling on that connection string by adding `Pooling=false`:

```
const string testConnectionString = @"Server=.; Database=RepoTest; Trusted_Connection=True;Pooling=false;";
```